# Why doesn't my STM32F4 PLL seem to work?

Tags: c, arm, stm32f4, pll, cortex-m4

I've spent a few days unsuccessfully trying to get my Nucleo F401RE to use the PLL for its system clock. I've configured it to use the 8MHz HSE and output 84MHz as the system clock. The code stops executing when it gets to:

```c
// Wait for clock source to change
    while ((RCC_CFGR & (2 << RCC_CFGR_SWS_BIT)) == 0);
```

I'm outputting the PLL clock on MCO1 and the HSE on MCO2, and I see a flat (high) PLL and an 8MHz HSE. I presume SWS never indicates the PLL is the system clock because the PLL is not correctly configured, but it does make it past waiting for PLLRDY.

I'm using the following code (specifically not using CMSIS, because I want to figure this out manually):

```c
#include "stm32f4.h"

#include <stdbool.h>

void led(bool on) {
    GPIOA_ODR = on ? 1 << 5 : 0;
}

void init(void) {
    // Enable GPIOA peripheral clock
    RCC_AHB1ENR = RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN | RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN;

    // Set PA5 to output and PA8 to MCO1
    GPIOA_MODER = 0b01 << 10 | 0b10 << 16;

    // Set PC9 MCO2
    GPIOC_MODER = 0b10 << 18;

    // Turn on HSE
    RCC_CR |= RCC_CR_HSEON;
    while ((RCC_CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY) == 0);

    // Set flash wait cycles
    FLASH_ACR = FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN | (2 << FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_BIT);

    // Configure PLL
    // System clock = 84MHz, PLL48CLK = 48MHz
    RCC_PLLCFGR = (RCC_PLLCFGR & RCC_PLLCFGR_RESERVED_MASK)
        | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC // Set HSE as PLL source
        | (4 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_BIT) // M = 4
        | (168 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_BIT) // N = 168
        | (1 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_BIT) // P = 4
        | (7 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_BIT) // Q = 7
    ;

    // Turn on PLL
    RCC_CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while ((RCC_CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY) == 0);

    RCC_CFGR = 
        (1 << RCC_CFGR_SW_BIT) // Use PLL as clock source
        | (0b11 << 21) // Output PLL on MCO1
        | (0b10 << 30) // Output HSE on MCO2
    ;

    // LED lights if set here

    // Wait for clock source to change
    while ((RCC_CFGR & (2 << RCC_CFGR_SWS_BIT)) == 0);

    // LED doesn't light here
    led(true);

    for (;;);
}
```

with these headers:

```c
#ifndef STM32F4_H
#define STM32F4_H

#include <stdint.h>

#define REGISTER(addr) (*(volatile uint32_t *)(addr))

#define GPIOA_BASE 0x40020000
#define GPIOA_MODER REGISTER(GPIOA_BASE + 0x00)
#define GPIOA_OTYPER REGISTER(GPIOA_BASE + 0x04)
#define GPIOA_PUPDR REGISTER(GPIOA_BASE + 0x0c)
#define GPIOA_ODR REGISTER(GPIOA_BASE + 0x14)

#define GPIOC_BASE 0x40020800
#define GPIOC_MODER REGISTER(GPIOC_BASE + 0x00)

#define RCC_BASE 0x40023800

#define RCC_CR REGISTER(RCC_BASE + 0x00)
#define RCC_CR_HSEON (1 << 16)
#define RCC_CR_HSERDY (1 << 17)
#define RCC_CR_PLLON (1 << 24)
#define RCC_CR_PLLRDY (1 << 25)

#define RCC_PLLCFGR REGISTER(RCC_BASE + 0x04)
#define RCC_PLLCFGR_RESERVED_MASK 0b11110000101111001000000000000000
#define RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_BIT 0
#define RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_BIT 6
#define RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_BIT 16
#define RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC (1 << 22)
#define RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_BIT 24

#define RCC_CFGR REGISTER(RCC_BASE + 0x08)
#define RCC_CFGR_SW_BIT 0
#define RCC_CFGR_SWS_BIT 2

#define RCC_AHB1ENR REGISTER(RCC_BASE + 0x30)
#define RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN (1 << 0)
#define RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN (1 << 2)

#define FLASH_BASE 0x40023C00
#define FLASH_ACR REGISTER(FLASH_BASE + 0x00)
#define FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_BIT 0
#define FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN (1 << 8)

#define NVIC_ISER0 0xE000E100

#define SYST_CSR REGISTER(0xE000E010)
#define SYST_CSR_COUNTFLAG (1 << 16)

#define SYST_RVR REGISTER(0xE000E014)
#define SYST_CVR REGISTER(0xE000E018)

#endif
```

Comment: Well for one you are definitely not switching to PLL but to HSE as clock source - though with your config that should also be possible and the LED should turn on.

Comment: Okay, so I changed that to PLL, and now the LED does light, but I still just get high on MCO1 (it does show HSE if I switch it to that).

Comment: If I set MCO1PRE to /4, I get a 21MHz output, so the PLL itself seems to be fine now. The manual says MCO should be able to go up to 100MHz, though.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out—I had to set the GPIO output speed to high speed.

Comment: You probably need to set the `GPIO_OSPEEDR` for the corresponding pin to high to get 84 MHz out of the pin. And it might not be strong enough to drive the capacity presented by your probe.

Comment: I don't have time to spare for an answer, so you should go ahead and answer your own question with the findings - comments could be gone if someone else comes to find a similar answer.

Comment: Why is there a 2 in a bit mask in `RCC_CFGR & (2 << RCC_CFGR_SWS_BIT)`? Shouldn't that be a `1`?

Comment: @TurboJ no, the code is waiting for the PLL to be selected. The SWS is a two bit value and PLL selection has the value of 2.

Comment: why aren'y you use CMSIS definitions instead of your ones? Writing own ones for the whole core & peripherals is as insane job. Why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: It's a learning exercise.